# Help balancing a dragon fight for an 8th-level party

Tags: dnd-5e, encounter-design, dragons

When my 5 players go up to 8th level, they will be encountering their first dragon. I need help building an encounter that will feel tense without a TPK.

To create a deadly encounter using [Kobold Fight Club](http://kobold.club/), I determined this encounter:

- **1x Young Silver Dragon (CR 9)**
- **3x Magma Mephit (CR 1/2)**

But is a CR 9 too weak, and should I be looking at a higher CR? I know the DMG warns against using CRs higher than your average party level.

I know a lot can change based on terrain, but I just wanted to get a ball-park idea of what you all think.

Comment: Please note we're not a forum and don't handle open-ended "what do you all think" type questions. Instead, try asking about the actual problem you're facing. Why do you think CR 9 is too weak and that you should be looking for a higher CR? What about the encounter as a whole do you have a problem with and feel needs balancing out? Explain to us the actual problem and we're more likely to be able to help.

Comment: On the other hand, the [forums we recommend](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/23970), including our very own [chat], *do* handle "what do you all think" very well. So there're options, too.